# 送信メールサーバと受信メールサーバを分けたい

Tags: dns, postfix, mail

こんにちは。

現在Webが利用する送信メールサーバのあるWeb用のサーバと、一般の（人による）総受信メールサーバを独立に動かしています。Webアプリケーションによる自動送信はPostfixによって行えることが確認できているのですが、受信が同一のドメインで別サーバで行う方法がわからず悩んでいます。

**サーバ構成**

2つのサーバは物理的に別れています。

送信メールサーバはPostfixによって運用されており、DNSレコードは以下のとおりです。

```
@ A 163.xx.xx.xxx
@ MX 10 xx.example.com
@ TXT v=spf1 +ip4:163.xx.xx.xxx -all
```

**対策**

一般の送受信を行いたいメールサーバのIPアドレスが`210.yy.yy.yyy`のときに上記の内容を達成するために以下の方法を思いついたのですがうまく動きません。

1. MX レコードを変更する (MX 10 210.yy.yy.yyy. のような感じで)
2. Postfixのrelay_domains, transportを利用して転送する
3. Webが利用する送信サーバを一般に利用しているものに変更する

MXレコードを変更した場合Postfixの送信ができなくなる&なりすまし対策が不可能か。
Postfixの転送を利用は試してみたのですがうまく動かず。

**エラー内容**

> Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table

このエラーはWeb用のサーバ(163.xx.xx.xxx)から発行されており, リレー自体ができていない？ようです。

3番は行わないで解決したいです。

**質問**

MXレコードの編集で解決できるのならばそれが一番簡単かと思うのですが、レコードの編集で上記の内容を達成することは可能でしょうか。つまりxx.example.comよりWeb用サーバからPostfixを利用して自動送信を行い、xx.example.com宛のメールは210.yy...のサーバで受け取る。また210.yy...のサーバからもメールがxx.example.comから送信できるようにする。ということです。

もしくはPostfixの転送を利用する場合、

```
relay_domains = example.com

example.com smtp:210.yy.yy.yyy
```

の設定(postmap, reload済み)の他にどうすれば達成できるでしょうか。

## 追記

Web用サーバ) *163.xx.xx.xxx, xx.example.com*
メール送受信サーバ) *210.yy.yy.yyy, yy.example.jp*

本日再度送信してみたところ210.yy.yy.yyyで受信することができました。
皆さんお手数をおかけいたしました。

昨日と設定を変更しておらず、なぜ受信できるようになったのか不明なのですが
昨日,変更したところは

- Postfixのrelay_domainsとtransport,
- MXレコード(`MX 10 xx.example.com` から`MX 10 yy.example.jp` に変更)

です。

**Postfixログ**

> Nov  1 12:00:13 example postfix/smtpd[9206]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-pg0-f41.google.com[74.125.83.41]: 550 5.1.1 user@xx.example.com: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from=test@gmail.com to=user@xx.example.com proto=ESMTP helo=mail-pg0-f41.google.co

注) toやfromの<>を消しています

Comment: エラー：Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient tableは、メールアドレスが存在しないとエラーを吐いている様な、メールアドレスが登録されていないので拒否されたと思います。

Comment: MXレコードは配送先のメールドメインを記述するところで、送信するサーバはMXレコード指定じゃないサーバでもいいことは理解していますでしょうか？

Comment: @keitaro_so はい。もともとあったMXを書き換えて210.yy.yy.yyyを指しているFQDNを設定し、dnsが変わっていることをdigコマンドで確認後に送信してみたのですがfailureになってしまいます。210~の方にメールアドレスが存在することは確認済みです。163~のサーバにはメールアドレスを登録する必要はないですよね...?210~のドメインではもちろん受信可能なのですが、163~(example.com)で受信したいのです。

Comment: @yhtsk 210.yy.yy.yyyと163~(example.‌​com)両方で受信をしたいということですか？

Comment: @keitaro_so  163~(example.com)では受信しないです。210~の方のみで受信したいです。user@example.comのアドレスを210~(別のドメイン, example.jp)で受信したいです。

Comment: 163.xx.xx.xxx は FQDN が xx.example.com で送信専用、210.yy.yy.yyy は FQDN が yy.example.jp で送受信用。
この時、xx.example.com で発生した user@example.com 宛メールを yy.example.jp で受信するにはどう設定すればいいか?
ということですか?

Comment: @masm はい。その通りです！説明がわかりにくくて申し訳ないです。

Comment: 210.yy.yy.yyyにはuser@example.com のメール設定はされているのですよね？メールログなどではどのように表記されているでしょうか？

Comment: 追加情報は質問を編集して追記してください。

Answer (score 1):

Web サーバー上の Postfix が `example.com` を自ドメインと認識(ローカル配送の対象)しており、かつ Web サービスから受信したメールの宛先を見つけることができないために発生しているのだと思います。

以下の要領で Postfix `postconf`(1) を実行して `mydestination` に `example.com` が含まれてないか確認してみてください。

```
$ postconf mydestination
```

`mydestination` に `example.com` が含まれているなら、それを削除してください。

同じ要領でリレー許可関係のパラメーターも確認してみてください。下記の例に含まれる `compatibility_level` は、古い Postfix では該当パラメーターが存在しないため警告が出力されますが無視してください。

```
$ postconf compatibility_level mynetworks mynetworks_style relay_domains smtpd_relay_restrictions smtpd_recipient_restrictions
```

一般的な設定であれば、ローカル (127.0.0.1, ::1) からのリレーは許可されていると思います。

詳細はオンラインマニュアル `postconf`(5) をどうぞ。

上記パラメーターや現在値と変更値の意味がわからないのであれば、Postfix の構築・運用するのは危険です。専門の人や業者に頼ることを推奨します。